# margin-top is not applying to child elements of a button in latest versions of both safari and chrome (webkit)

Tags: css, webkit

The anchor tag and div apply the margin-top property to the child elements just fine, however the button can not.

I have tested in latest versions of safari, chrome and firefox.
Firefox has no issues provided the -moz-focus-inner property is applied, i'm wondering if there may be a similar issue with webkit?

http://jsfiddle.net/Ym3BL/1/

Does anyone know how to make the three items style the same/ or how to allow for margin-top in webkit browsers?

Many Thanks

-Jai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out and feel like a numpty.

The key property is `-webkit-margin-top-collapse:separate;` applied to the child element, this doesn't quite make sense to me still, as the parent element has no margin or padding so therefore why should i need to separate the margins?

however it works so i'm not complaining

http://jsfiddle.net/Ym3BL/2/